# New-AzureRmDnsZone cmdlet do not able to find resource group

Tags: azure, dns, azure-powershell

I created a DNS Zone and a custom resource group 'Default-DNS-Zone' from portal but on shell prompt, executing below command throws Default-DNS-Zone not found. I still was able to do it from portal again.

```
PS C:\HBala> New-AzureRmDnsZone -Name www.example.com -ResourceGroupName Default-DNS-Zone
```

> New-AzureRmDnsZone : ResourceGroupNotFound: Resource group 'Default-DNS-Zone' could not be found.
>   At line:1 char:1

Would it be anything to do with the OS support for the cmdlet? I use Windows 7.

Comment: What happens when you run `Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -name "Default-DNS-Zone"`? You can also try to run the Cmdlet in debug mode by adding `-Debug` parameter at the end of the Cmdlet.

Comment: @GauravMantri Nopes, This is still same. I Logged in, tried to set the subscription to 'production' and queried your command to get the following: ResourceGroupName : Default-DNS-Zone
Location          : eastus
ProvisioningState : Succeeded
Tags              : 
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/Default-DNS-Zone

Comment: @GauravMantri : PS C:\Users\HBala> $parent = Get-AzureRmDnsZone -Name {root_domain} -ResourceGroupName Default-DNS-Zone
Get-AzureRmDnsZone : ResourceNotFound: The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/dnszones/{root_domain}' under resource group 'Default-DNS-Zone' was not found.

Comment: @GauravMantri Interestingly, only one of my subscription ( production one gives this error ) . Dev subscription works fine. Earlier, I checked your recommended against Dev to find it working.

Comment: Using Windows 7 should not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you're convinced that you are using the correct resource group name and subscription (please double-check!) then the next step should be to raise a Support ticket so the issue can be assigned to an engineer for further investigation.